# syntax error in from clause while the same code works fine for other table

Tags: ms-access

This is my following code
cmd=new oledbcommand("select * from social where name='ragu' ")
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()

The above code works well for the table social but it is not working when i change the table name from social to general

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? It's not ASP.NET question but rather SQL question.

Comment: sry .I changed my tag. Iam using ms access 2013

Answer (score 1):

`General` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose that table name in square brackets.

```sql
select * from [general] AS g where g.name='ragu'
```

`Name` is also a reserved word.  You could also bracket that field name, but prefixing it with the table alias is sufficient.